# Issue with Putty EC2 connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to EC2 and I am getting this error:

```
Using username "ec2-user"
Server refused our key 
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

I am using `Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type` so my username is correct. I have also converted the pem file into ppk file and added into SSH-Auth in putty console.

I have looked at all the solutions in StackOverflow for my problem but none seem to work.

In my VPC dashboard -> Network ACLs -> Inbound Rules

```
Rule # Type         Protocol   Port Range   Source    Allow / Deny
100    ALL Traffic   ALL       ALL     0.0.0.0/0      ALLOW
*      ALL Traffic   ALL       ALL     0.0.0.0/0      DENY
```

Could this be a reason for the error?

Answer (score 1):

The **Network Access Control List (NACL)** is not a problem. Just leave it at the default setting. The fact that you are connecting to the server (even though it is refusing the connection) is proof that there is connectivity between your computer and the Amazon EC2 instance.

**The problem lies in authentication.** It is basically saying that it doesn't like your key pair.

- Make sure the PEM file that you converted has the same name as the **Key Pair** associated with the instance (as shown in the management console)
- Try converting the key again -- it might not be in the right format

**See:** [Use PuTTY to access EC2 Linux Instances via SSH from Windows](https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/17385-use-putty-to-access-ec2-linux-instances-via-ssh-from-windows) (You don't need to use Pageant.)

Comment: I am stuck at the same issue :(. Tried to generate a new key pair and pointed to the new ppk file, extracted from puttgen. Still getting the same error

Comment: Try launching a new instance with the same keypair and see if you can login with it. That will tell you whether your key generation process is working correctly. Alternatively, [try a different SSH utility](https://www.htpcbeginner.com/best-ssh-clients-windows-putty-alternatives/2/) -- PuTTY (and its variants) is the only program that uses PPK files. Try MobaXterm -- it can use a PEM file.

Comment: yes MobaXterm worked!, however what is the right way to convert from pem to ppk using putty

Comment: PuTTYGen will convert it. You have to load the key, then save it without a password. You're much better off avoiding PuTTY.