# Can't connect to EC2 instance via Putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

I am doing Team Project about Web Server and streaming.

One of my team member has created Instance, and I want to use that instance.
He and I are both IAM user.

But when I tried to use SSH connect by PUTTY, there was an error:

```
no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey)
```

[image: no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey)]

Is it because trying to access with my IAM account, but the owner of that instance is my team member? How can I connect his AWS EC2 instance with my account (using PUTTY)?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have pem file?

Comment: You need to use ssh private key. To use IAM authentication, you have to use SSM Session Manager.

Comment: Yes I got pem file and generated ppk by using PuttyGen. But after that I got that error. :(

Answer (score 1):

This  error is similar like setting up AWS SSH for the first time, possible problems?

- Incorrect .ppk file, Wrong username, Wrong IP.

Also check  permission of your pem file

```
/folder/ec2-user/ - 700

/folder/ec2-user/.ssh/ -600

/folder/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys - 600
```

This post may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112210/13126651

if it doesnt

**First of all make sure your security group attached to Ec2-instace allows inbound connection to ssh on port 22**

the usual default username in EC2 for these Linux distro:

```
Amazon Linux: ec2-user
Ubuntu: ubuntu
Debian : admin
```

then, if you are using :

```
Windows - get PEM key from AWS website and generate PPK file using PuttyGen. Then use Putty to use the PPK (select it using left-column: Connection->SSH->Auth: Private key for authorization)
```

for Linux

```
Linux - run: ssh -i your-ssh-key.pem login@IP-or-DNS
```

*there is one more sleek method to connect to your instance which doesn't require any pem file from your end since authentication key is stored on was side*

```
To access the instance through a browser, make sure you add a rule in your security group to allow port 80 and port 443 inbound.
```

under your instance, you can see `connect`, click on it and select connect using the browser

Aws doc for troubleshooting, this error [check this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/linux-credentials-error/)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I will try your answer.